# Tastypie resource name clash

Tags: django, tastypie

I am currently using tastypie with 2 apps. Each of those apps has a model called Group. They operate very differently, and the only similarity is the name 'Group'.

When only one or the other app is added to the urls file, then it works like a charm. However, as soon as I add both apps, then there's a name clash, and the get_resource_uri() method returns the wrong string. Here is some code:

**urls.py**

```
from myapp1.resources import GroupResource as gr_a
from myapp2.resources import GroupResource as gr_b

myapp1_api = Api(api_name='1.0')
myapp1_api.register(gr_a())

myapp2_api = Api(api_name='1.0')
myapp2_api.register(gr_b())
```

on line 37 of the current api.py file in the tastypie repo I see this code:

```
if resource_name is None:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Resource %r must define a 'resource_name'." % resource)

 self._registry[resource_name] = resource
```

Since both of my Group resources have the resource_name of 'group', they get registered on top of each other, even though they are registered at separate urls. Apart from changing the actual resource name, is there a way around this name clash?

**Update**
The uris would look something like this:

```
/myapp1/1.0/group/
/myapp2/1.0/group/
```

Ideally I don't want myapp1 and myapp2 to know about each other (ie the Group class is distinct). The workaround for this is to change myapp2.Group to myapp2.MyGroup (to avoid the name clash), but its really not that elegant.

Comment: Are you setting resource_name in the resource Meta? if you don't it will default to the class name. http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-resources

Comment: I'm not. I suppose I could, but I want the resource name to be the same as the class name since I'd prefer if the url remains unchanged. Changing the resource name in the Meta unfortunately also affects the api url for that class.

Comment: What are the resource URIs for both of them? I.e. at what URLs do you access them?

Comment: @Geevious, if you solved the problem, please provide an answer. If you haven't please give us more information so that we can help...

Comment: I haven't solved it, and have merely renamed the class as a workaround for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all my resources I had the resource_name blank, since I was happy with the default name. Also I wanted a url such as /myapp/1.0/group/ and not /myapp/1.0/myapp/group/

What I've now done is change all the resource_name attributes to the form "myapp/group" and bound them all to an empty url. This gave me a nice such as: /1.0/myapp/group/ while making sure there are no name clashes in the resources.